# How to use Data Binding and Kotlin in Android Studio 3.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-databinding, android-studio-3.0

I just started to use Android Studio 3.0.0, but every time I try to build my project I get this error:

```
Error:Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:compileDebugKotlin
+--- :app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug
|    \--- :app:compileDebugKotlin (*)
\--- :app:kaptDebugKotlin
     \--- :app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug (*)
(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

I am using

```
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.2.0"
```

Before I was using

```
androidProcessor "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.2.0"
```

And it was working just fine... What I am doing wrong??

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a bug, created issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17936

Comment: This bug appear even without any data binding. You just use 1.1.2-4 version of kotlin and apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'. Then you will get this error
Error:Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:compileDebugKotlin
\--- :app:kaptDebugKotlin
     \--- :app:compileDebugKotlin (*)
(*) - details omitted (listed previously)

Comment: Also related issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38471980

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It seems that you need 3 gradle entries in the app .gradle at module level to add data binding

1. `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`
2. `android {
   ...
      dataBinding {
          enabled = true
      }
    }`
3. `dependencies {
       ......
       kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$compiler_version"
    }`

Notice that I made compiler version a variable in the project level build gradle so it can be managed from a single place

default was: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'`

I added with bracket syntax:

```
ext{
    kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    compiler_version = '3.0.0-beta6'
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, to add kotlin-kapt and that dependency line. The top answer isn't relevant any more

Comment: Liked the use of the version variable

Comment: I am getting: - with all versions

[kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @PavelZaitsev I haven't used android studio in a while

Answer (score 80):

**UPD:** This was fixed for Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha3, in yout project root `build.gradle`, change the `buildscript` `dependencies` to use

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
```

---

This is actually a bug in the Kotlin Gradle plugin 1.1.2-4 inter-operation with the Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0-alpha1, caused by how the inputs and outputs of the tasks are set (and thus how the tasks are connected with the depends-on relation).

Thanks [@VyacheslavGerasimov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6275756/vyacheslav-gerasimov) for creating the issue [KT-17936](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17936).

---

As a temporary workaround, you can try to revert to Kotlin Gradle plugin 1.1.2-2 and disable incremental compilation:

In your project's root `build.gradle`, change the version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2-2'
    }
}
```

Add `local.properties` to the project root, with the following line:

```
kotlin.incremental=false
```

<sup>It is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17642) that the Kotlin Gradle plugin 1.1.2-2 and below crashes with the newest AGP versions, and disabling incremental compilation seems to fix that crash.</sup>

Comment: I believe you meant gradle.properties

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira, you use can any of them, because Gradle detects and interprets the `local.properties` file in your projects as well. Well, maybe `local.properties` is more suitable for *local machine* properties.

Comment: This leads to this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056104/gradle-3-0-0-alpha1-isnt-compatible-with-kotlin-android-plugin-1-1-2-3

Comment: @gderaco, make sure you disable Kotlin incremental compilation. The error you mentioned is caused by the incompatibility of the incremental compilation code in 1.1.2 with the newer Android Gradle plugin.

Comment: Actually to revert to 1.1.2-3 also works fine. Same issue with Android Studio  2.3.2 and gradle 2.3.2 when using Kotlin 1.1.2-4 together with kotlin-kapt plugin

Comment: @hotkey based on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38447344 this is an issue in the Android plugin, not kotlin gradle plugin. A fix was made and is planned to be released in the next 3.0.0 alpha release.

Comment: @Arsenius how you reverted? Did you switch to stable release of android studio?

Comment: @LostinBielefeld just use classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" where kotlin_version 1.1.2-3
Yes I'm using stable release 2.3.2

Answer (score 18):

For those still looking for a proper solution, Google has already fixed this issue in [Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-3-is-now.html) build.

Friday, June 2, 2017

> We have just released Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3 to the Canary and
>   Dev Channels. The Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0-alpha3 was also released
>   through maven.google.com. This release has fixes to **Gradle**, **Kotlin**,
>   and many other fixes. We continue to fix bugs in all areas of Studio
>   3.0 as we stabilize our features, so please continue to pass on feedback.

Working gradle configuration:

**build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


android {
    dataBinding.enabled = true
}
dependencies {
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0-alpha3"
}
```

Comment: How to fix this issue in Android Studio 2.3.2?

Comment: You can use an older version of Kotlin plugin with incremental false. Check the previous answer by "hotkey"

Comment: No, `1.1.2-4` still doesn't work. One still has to use `1.1.2-2` and also add kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0-alpha3" to your build.gradle (module) or you will get Unresolved reference: databinding.

Comment: Not fixed on 1.1.2-5 as well

Answer (score 4):

If you use Kotlin Gradle plugin 1.3 and higher, you do not need to specify `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$plugin_version"`

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32057

It is enough to specify `dataBinding` in your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

or

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

Comment: but you still get a warning, unless you add `//noinspection DataBindingWithoutKapt`

Answer (score 0):

in Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1 and gradle v8.7
for kotlin
build.gradle.kts (project) add:

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid) apply false
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.9.0"  apply false //add this line<don't tell anyone:)
}
```

and
build.gradle.kts (app) add:

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    id ("kotlin-kapt")// add this line

}

android {
...
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        viewBinding = true//this 
        dataBinding = true//and this add both!

    }
}
```

noting else need
Just don't forget in xml must use data classs:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.example.model.User" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{user.name}" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

and in your activity:

```
// Get a binding instance for your layout
val binding: ActivityMainBinding =  DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
// Create a User object with data
val user = User("John")
// Set the user data on the binding variable
binding.user = user
```