# Gradle 3.0.0-alpha1 isn't compatible with kotlin-android plugin 1.1.2-3?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I Install Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1 and create new project with kotlin.
And get this error:

> Error:Unable to find method
>   'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may
>     solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>     processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a
>     third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in
>     the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
>     project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

If i remove kotlin-android plugin from build.gradle it's successfully building.

Build gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-3'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app\build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dmytrobazunov.databasetest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
```

Does someone knowes how to fix this issue?

Comment: You could improve your "duplicate" response by linking to the duplicate question and answer.  Not all of us have found that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to change the Kotlin plugin version to `1.1.2-4`.

Comment: I have the same issue even I used this kotlin version

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you import settings from previous version of Android Studio. Bump your kotlin plugin version to `1.1.2-4` and delete folder `~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioPreview3.0/Kotlin` (if you're using mac for example)