# No way to compile my own kotlin library

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, jitpack, android-studio-3.0

With Google I/O 2017, I decided to learn kotlin by developing my own library in kotlin for android. This library allows to get information from OpenWeatherMap API.
Link of the project : https://github.com/sokarcreative/EasyOWM

What's the problem ?
I just can't compile my library. I tried everything.
I have already compiled forked project and it worked but no way with my own library.

I created a new project with these `gradlew` scripts :

-- Project gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
       ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

-- module gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.github.sokarcreative:easyowm:master-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Error : `Failed to resolve: com.github.sokarcreative:easyowm:master-SNAPSHOT`

I know this is a recurring question but no way to solve this problem.

Edit: just in case, the library works.
Here is the result on my galaxy tab S3:
[EasyOWM screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8wEM.png)

Comment: The error is :
No build artifacts found
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
         > com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;

from https://jitpack.io/com/github/sokarcreative/easyowm/v1.0/build.log

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056104/gradle-3-0-0-alpha1-isnt-compatible-with-kotlin-android-plugin-1-1-2-3

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that : changing
`
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-3'

to

ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'

but I downgraded because of this error : 
`
Error:Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:compileDebugKotlin
\--- :app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug
     \--- :app:compileDebugKotlin (*)
(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
`
This didn't fix the problem for me but generate another one.
Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: Need to wait Android Studio 3.0 alpha3 according to : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38447344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved with Android Studio 3.0 canary 3