# Android Studio 3 + Gradle 4.0 + shrinkResources + libraryProject = Unable to find a matching configuration in project

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-build-type, android-studio-3.0

I've problems to migrate my project to the newest Gradle 4.0 + Android Studio 3 version, which gives me all kind of errors. Little by little I managed to sort them all out except this one.

```
    Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:forGoogleCoverageRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Unable to find a matching configuration in project :mylibrary:
       - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
           - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' and found compatible value 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}'.
           - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=coverage}' and found incompatible value 'BuildTypeAttr{name=debug}'.
           - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=debug}' but wasn't required.
           - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for runtime' and found incompatible value 'for compile'.
           - Required store 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=forGoogle}' but no value provided.
       - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
           - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' and found compatible value 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}'.
           - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=coverage}' and found incompatible value 'BuildTypeAttr{name=debug}'.
           - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=debug}' but wasn't required.
           - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for runtime' and found compatible value 'for runtime'.
           - Required store 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=forGoogle}' but no value provided.
       - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
           - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' and found compatible value 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}'.
           - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=coverage}' and found incompatible value 'BuildTypeAttr{name=release}'.
           - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=release}' but wasn't required.
           - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for runtime' and found incompatible value 'for compile'.
           - Required store 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=forGoogle}' but no value provided.
       - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
           - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}' and found compatible value 'AndroidTypeAttr{name=Aar}'.
           - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BuildTypeAttr 'BuildTypeAttr{name=coverage}' and found incompatible value 'BuildTypeAttr{name=release}'.
           - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'VariantAttr{name=release}' but wasn't required.
           - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'for runtime' and found compatible value 'for runtime'.
           - Required store 'ProductFlavorAttr{name=forGoogle}' but no value provided.
```

In order to nail down the problem:

1. I've created a minimum app project from Android Studios project assistant
2. added an empty library module which I then add to my app dependencies.
3. added one flavorDimensions and 2 productFlavors
4. added 3 build types and let one build type inherit from another
5. **let the inherited build type enable `shrinkResources`**

The last step produces the mentioned error, which is similar to this question:
[Gradle 4.0 Unable to find a matching configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218614/gradle-4-0-unable-to-find-a-matching-configuration)

Has anybody an idea what's the matter here or an solution to this problem? I'll file a bug report too.

My complete gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gradletest.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    flavorDimensions "store"

    productFlavors {
        forAmazon {
            dimension "store"
        }

        forGoogle {
            dimension "store"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        coverage.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        coverage {
            testCoverageEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation project(':mylibrary')
}
```

Comment: Bug report under: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62170415 feel free to star. For now it helps me to remove the shrinkResources from my build type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possible workaround is create in all modules missing buildTypes, but it's crazy messing code when Google planed create a sollution for it. More info in: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62170415 as me (but deleted by moderator) and you mention.

But there is second (same but much cleaner) solution:
add this to your top project `build.gradle`

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                buildTypes {
                    YOUR_MISSING_BUILD_TYPES {
                       BUILD_TYPE_PARAMS_OR_EMPTY
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: 2017-07-12**

It's finally fixed in `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6'`.
You can use new DSL: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62241369

```
android {
  buildTypeMatching 'staging', 'debug'
  productFlavorMatching 'color', 'blue', 'cyan'
}
```

**Don't forgot to remove above workaround before build project!**

**EDIT: 2017-07-18**

There is official documentation: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62241369

> To resolve this error, you need to specify which build type from
>   "mylibrary" the Android plugin should match to the app's "staging"
>   build type. You can do this with the buildTypeMatching property in the
>   app's build.gradle file, as shown below:

```
// Add the following to the consumer's build.gradle file.
android {
    ...
    // Tells the Android plugin to use a library's 'debug' build type
    // when a 'staging' build type is not available. You can include
    // additional build types, and the plugin matches 'staging' to the
    // first build type it finds from the one's you specify. That is,
    // if 'mylibrary' doesn't include a 'debug' build type either, the
    // plugin matches 'staging' with the producer's 'release' build type.
    buildTypeMatching 'staging', 'debug', 'release'
}
```

**EDIT: 2017-09-06**

`buildTypeMatching` has been removed from AS beta 4.
now use `matchingFallbacks`.
see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46038946/4594990

Comment: In my project, the build types in app module and lib module is 'debug' and 'release'. Tried putting buildTypeMatching 'debug', 'release' in app build.gradle. It still throws the same error https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#buildTypeMatching

Comment: Here is my build type for App & library https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1dda4a85d4d3c021a8fc07251901f9f2

Answer (score 3):

IF your app includes a build type that a library dependency does not.

For example, your app includes a "staging" build type, but a dependency includes only a "debug" and "release" build type.

You will get error like

`Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@staging/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :library. Open File Show Details`

You can resolve this error by adding

```
buildTypes {
        staging {
            proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')
            proguardFile 'dexguard-rules.pro'
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release'] //add this line
        }
    }
```

Resolve build errors related to dependency matching [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#flavor_dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

*Possible duplicate of [Gradle 4.0 Unable to find a matching configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218614/gradle-4-0-unable-to-find-a-matching-configuration/44510504#44510504)*

Make sure you have the **exact number of build configurations (buildTypes) in all of your modules**.

In my pre-3.0 setup, I was having only *debug{}* and *release{}* in all of my com.android.library modules. I added one more configuration similar to that of :app module. It builds fine for me.

Comment: Your way of doing, worked in Canary 4 and 6. In Canary 7 and Canary 8, it still throws an error

Comment: Here is my build type for App & library https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1dda4a85d4d3c021a8fc07251901f9f2

Answer (score 0):

if you reach here,then my solution is:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // minifyEnabled false
            // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        build {
            //   minifyEnabled false
            //   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```